If two sets of propostions entail something and the two sets don't entail each other can we say anything about the weakest set of propostions needed?
Suppose I have the following:

A proof that some set of propositions A, B, C imply M.
A separate proof that some different set of propositions X, Y, Z also imply M.
A proof that A, B, C does not imply X, Y, Z.
A proof that X, Y, Z does not imply A, B, C.

Do these 4 things say anything about the weakest possible propositions needed to imply M?

The weakest possible proposition needed to imply M is M, 1-4 are superfluous. You need some restriction on the "weakest set of propositions" to make this non-trivial.
